# Minimal polynomial of $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

> Find the minimal polynomial of $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta$ is primitive $13^{th}$ root of unity.

All I know is that the minimal polynomial should be of degree 6.

**My thougths**

Usually, given an element, say $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, to find the minimal polynomial, we take $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and the square it and do further simplifications to get a linear combination of powers of $\alpha$ (polynomial in $\alpha$) equal to zero, If the resulting polynomial is irreducible, we say it is a minimal polynomial for the given element over the given field. However, for the element $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ this way is too complicated.

Could you suggest some other procedure (if any) or a hint to simplify the calculation?

Comment: Are you familiar with Galois theory? This would offer one algorithm for writing down the minimal polynomial, namely just take the product of all $T-a$, where $a$ runs through the orbit of $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ under the Galois group (which is well-known).

Comment: Try writing it as 2 times cosine, and then thinking of same famous polynomial families.

Comment: @AlexYoucis : Thank You, I have $\zeta=cos(\frac{2\pi}{13})+isin(\frac{2\pi}{13})$ So, $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=2cos(\frac{2\pi}{13})$ and now i will find minimal polynomial for $2cos(\frac{2\pi}{13})$ which i am not very sure about at this time but i can do it. :) Thank YOu again!!

Comment: @AlexYoucis As $T_{13}(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{13}))=\cos(2\pi)=1$, it follows $2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{13})$ is a zero of $T_{13}(x/2)-1$. It appears that (via W|Alpha calculations) $$T_{13}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1=\frac{x-2}{2}[{\rm minpoly}_{\zeta+\zeta^{-1},\bf Q}(x)]^2.$$ Thus not clear to me how one would use Chebyshev polynomials to find the minimal polynomial of $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ on paper. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: @anon, I do not know anything about chebyeshev polynomials :O do i have to learn that to compute minimal polynomials of cosines and sines :( :(

Comment: Nope. I think Alex was referring to them as an interesting alternative to Galois theory, but I did some work and was unable to see this route through to the end. Thus I asked him if I understood him correctly.

Comment: Even i am not able to solve for minimal polyomial of cosine function immediately, but i hope i have read it some where. So, i am just trying to recollect :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Galois theory provides some machinery for this:

---

Suppose $\rm L/K$ is Galois with $\rm G=Gal(L/K)$ and $\rm m(x):=minpoly_{\alpha,K}(x)$. Then

$\quad \rm m(\sigma(\alpha))=\sigma(m(\alpha))=\sigma(0)=0$ implies $\rm (x-\sigma\alpha)\mid m$ in $\rm L[x]$ for all $\rm \sigma\in G$,

$\quad \rm(x-\sigma\alpha)$ all coprime, $\rm \sigma\in G/S$, $\rm S=Stab_G(\alpha)$, implies $\rm f(x):=\prod\limits_{\sigma\in G/S}(x-\sigma\alpha)\mid m$ in $\rm L[x]$,

$\quad \rm \sigma f(x)=f(x)$ for all $\sigma\in G$ implies $\rm f(x)\in K[x]$; $\rm f(\alpha)=0$ implies $\rm m(x)\mid f(x)$ in $\rm K[x]$,

$\quad \rm f(x)\mid m(x)$ and $\rm m(x)\mid f(x)$ and both $\rm f,m$ monic implies $\rm f(x)=m(x)$.

Therefore the zeros of $\rm\alpha$'s minimal polynomial over $\rm K$ are precisely its $\rm Gal(L/K)$-conjugates.

---

As ${\rm Gal}\big({\bf Q}(\zeta_n)/{\bf Q}\big)=({\bf Z}/n{\bf Z})^\times$ it suffices to consider $\sigma:\zeta\mapsto\zeta^k$ for $k=1,\cdots,12$.

By symmetry we need only consider $1,\cdots,6$ for $\alpha=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$. Thus

$$\begin{array}{ll} {\rm minpoly}_{\zeta+\zeta^{-1},\bf Q}(x) = & ~~~~\left(x-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})\right)\left(x-(\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2})\right)\left(x-(\zeta^3+\zeta^{-3})\right) \\ & \times\left(x-(\zeta^4+\zeta^{-4})\right)\left(x-(\zeta^5+\zeta^{-5})\right)\left(x-(\zeta^6+\zeta^{-6})\right). \end{array}$$

Simplify the resulting expansion via the rules $\zeta^n=\zeta^{n\,\bmod\,13}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{12}\zeta^k=0$.

Comment: Thank You for giving full detail Though i was waiting for a hint :)  Just before reading this with the hint of "Martin Brandenburg" above, I tried doing the same as noted here. Thank you again...

Comment: Why did you make everything in the first part of the answer in `\rm`, but in the second part you were so careful to control the scope of the various font commands? (+1 by the way)

Comment: @Zev: I guess I wanted theory to look rectilinear like an ancient austere structure and calculations to look curvilinear for modern sensibilities.

Answer (score 6):

Zero-theory computational approach:

Since $\zeta^{13}-1=0$, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{12}\zeta^k=0$ hence $1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^6x_k=0$, where $x_k=\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}$. Let $x=x_1$, then the system $x^k=\sum\limits_{2i\leqslant k}{k\choose i}x_{k-2i}$ for every $k\geqslant1$ is lower triangular with unknowns $(x_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ and unit diagonal hence each $x_k$ is a linear combination with integer coefficients of $x^i$ for $i\leqslant k$, for example $x_1=x$, $x_2=x^2-2$, $x_3=x^3-3x$, $x_4=x^4-4x^2+2$, and so on.

Thus, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^6x_k=P_6(x)$ where $P_6$ is a monic polynomial of degree $6$ with integer coefficients, and $P_6(x)+1=0$.

Comment: And yes, $P_k(2x)=2T_k(x)$...

Comment: It has been a while, must say, it's a beautiful answer!, I would like to ask, how can one justify that $P_{\frac{p-1}{2}} + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? ($p\in \mathbb{N}_{primes}$

Comment: @dan Thanks. If you have another problem, simply post it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is in response to the comment by @anon.

It isn't the case that Chebyshev polynomials are an alternative to Galois theory.  In an approach based on Chebyshev polynomials, you still need to first determine the degree $[{\bf Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}):{\bf Q}]$ via Galois theory.  But once you know this degree, then you can write down the minimal polynomial by means of Chebyshev polynomials.

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity, where $n$ is an arbitrary odd prime.  Writing $\alpha:=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$, we know via Galois theory that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over ${\bf Q}$ has degree $(n-1)/2$.  Thus, if we can write down a monic polynomial over ${\bf Q}$ of degree $(n-1)/2$ which has $\alpha$ as a root, then this polynomial will automatically be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over ${\bf Q}$.  To achieve this, recall that the Chebyshev polynomial $T_n(X)$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial in ${\bf Q}[X]$ which satisfies the functional equation
$$T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos(n\theta).$$
Write $z=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, so that $z+z^{-1}=2\cos\theta$ and thus
$$T_n\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}2\right)=\frac{z^n+z^{-n}}2.$$
It follows that
$$T_n\left(\frac{Z+Z^{-1}}2\right)=\frac{Z^n+Z^{-n}}2$$
is an equality of rational functions, since it is true for infinitely many values of $Z$.  Note that
$$T_n\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)=\frac{\zeta^n+\zeta^{-n}}2=1,$$
so $\alpha$ is a root of $T_n(X/2)-1$.  Now write $X=Z+Z^{-1}$, so that
$$T_n\left(\frac{X}2\right)-1 = \frac{Z^n+Z^{-n}}2 - 1 = \frac12 \left(Z^{n/2}-Z^{-n/2}\right)^2.$$
One can show directly that
$$\frac{Z^{n/2}-Z^{-n/2}}{Z^{1/2}-Z^{-1/2}}$$
is a polynomial $h(X)$ in ${\bf Z}[X]$ (in fact it is $U_{(n-1)/2}(X/2)+U_{(n-3)/2}(X/2)$, where $U_m(X)$ is the degree-$m$ Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind; see my answer to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464300/is-it-true-that-p-mid-mathbb-q-cos-frac-pip2-mathbb-q/464480#464480)).  Thus
$$T_n\left(\frac{X}2\right)-1 = \frac12 (Z^{1/2}-Z^{-1/2})^2 \cdot h(X)^2 =
\frac12(Z-2+Z^{-1})\cdot h(X)^2 = \frac{X-2}2\cdot h(X)^2.$$
Since $\alpha$ is a root of the left side, and $\alpha$ is not a root of $X-2$, it follows that $\alpha$ is a root of $h(X)$.  But $h(X)$ has degree $(n-1)/2$, and hence is a constant times the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over ${\bf Q}$.  In fact it's easy to check that $h(X)$ is monic, so it actually equals the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over ${\bf Q}$.  Hence the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over ${\bf Q}$ is $U_{(n-1)/2}(X/2) + U_{(n-3)/2}(X/2)$.  Now, for instance, we can write out the coefficients of this minimal polynomial, since we know that
$$
U_m\left(\frac{X}2\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\binom{m-k}k (-1)^k X^{m-2k}.$$
Strangely, this expression for the coefficients of $U_m$ doesn't seem to be in the wikipedia article for Chebyshev polynomials.  For a derivation of it from first principles, you can see for instance the beginning of [my paper with Abhyankar and Cohen](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~zieve/papers/acz.html).  In that paper we used Dickson polynomials rather than Chebyshev polynomials; the translations to the notation of this answer are $U_m(X/2)=E_m(X,1)$ and $2T_m(X/2)=D_m(X,1)$ (these translations follow from the relevant functional equations).

Answer (score 1):

We have the extensions
$$\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}( \zeta + \zeta^{-1}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$$

We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\colon \mathbb{Q}( \zeta + \zeta^{-1})]\le 2$, and also $\ne 1$, since one is real, and the other is not. Therefore, the degree is $2$, and therefore
$$ [\mathbb{Q}( \zeta + \zeta^{-1})\colon \mathbb{Q}] = \frac{1}{2} [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)\colon \mathbb{Q}]= \frac{\phi(n)}{2}$$

The minimal polynomial for $\zeta = \zeta_n$ is the cyclotomic polynomial of order $n$
$$\Phi_n(X)= \prod_{d \mid n} (X^{\frac{n}{d}}-1)^{\mu(d)} = \prod_{d \mid n} (1 + X + \cdots X^{\frac{n}{d} - 1})^{\mu(d)}$$

We see from the above that $\Phi_n(X)$ is [palyndromic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_and_antipalindromic_polynomials). We have therefore

$$\Phi_n(X) = X^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}} Q( X+ \frac{1}{X})$$ where $\deg Q = \frac{\phi(n)}{2}$

In our case $n=13$,
$$\Phi_{13}(X) = \frac{X^{13}-1}{X-1}= (1+X + \cdots +X^{12}) = X^6( X^6 + \frac{1}{X^6} + X^{5}+ \frac{1}{X^5} + \cdots + X + \frac{1}{X} + 1)$$

We can use a CAS ([WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7B%20y%20-%20%28x%5E%2813%29-1%29%2F%28x%5E6%28x-1%29%29%2C%20z%20-%20%28x%2B1%2Fx%29%7D%2C%7By%2Cz%7D%2C%7Bx%7D%5D)) to express $\frac{x^{13}-1}{x^6(x-1)}$ as a polynomial in $x+ \frac{1}{x}$

$$\frac{x^{13}-1}{x^6(x-1)} =z^6 + z^5 - 5 z^4 - 4 z^3 + 6 z^2 + 3 z - 1$$
where $z= x+ \frac{1}{x}$. Therefore
$Q(z) = z^6 + z^5 - 5 z^4 - 4 z^3 + 6 z^2 + 3 z - 1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{13} + \zeta_{13}^{-1}$, as one can [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=MinimalPolynomial%5B2%20Cos%5B2Pi%2F13%5D%2C%20z%5D).