# Prove that $\theta$ is an irrational multiple of $2\pi$ given $\cos(\theta/2)\equiv \cos^2(\pi/8)$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, irrational-numbers

> How do we prove that $\theta$ is an irrational multiple of $2\pi$ given $\cos(\theta/2)\equiv \cos^2(\pi/8)$?

With $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ rotations,

\begin{align}R_z(\pi/4)R_x(\pi/4)&=[\cos(\pi/8)I-i\sin(\pi/8)Z][\cos(\pi/8)I-i\sin(\pi/8)X]\\
&=\cos^2(\pi/8)I-i[\cos(\pi/8)X+\sin(\pi/8)Y+\cos(\pi/8)Z]\sin(\pi/8)\\
&=\cos(\theta/2)I-i(\hat{n}.\vec{\sigma})\sin(\theta/2)=R_\hat{n}(\theta)\end{align}

where $\vec{n}=(\cos(\pi/8),\sin(\pi/8),\cos(\pi/8))$ and $\hat{n}=\frac{\vec{n}}{||\vec{n}||}$, and $\vec{\sigma}=(X,Y,Z)$ where $X,Y,Z$ are Pauli matrices. Thus $\cos(\theta/2)\equiv\cos^2(\pi/8)$ and $\sin(\theta/2)\equiv\sin(\pi/8)\sqrt{1+\cos^2(\pi/8)}$.

**Original Context in my Reference**

Ref. to [Page 196, 214 of QC and QI by Nelsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

[image]

Any hint on the possible ways to approach this could be appreciated.

**Note :** [Publication which possibly contains the proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9906054.pdf)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with group theory.

Comment: @Shaun It may not be a right tag, just added because SU(2) rotation in involved.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't parse that part at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p,q$ be positive coprime integers and suppose by contradiction that $\theta=2\pi p/q$. Since $\cos^2(\pi/8)=(2+\sqrt2)/4$, it has algebraic degree $2$. By considering Galois conjugates of primitive roots of unity, we can [show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/464480/471884) over the rationals, the algebraic degree of $\cos(p\pi/q)$ is $\phi(q)$ when $q$ is even, and $\phi(q)/2$ when $q$ is odd.

Therefore, we have $\phi(q)=2$ when $q$ is even, giving $q=4,6$ (when $q$ is odd there are no solutions to $\phi(q)=4$). As none of $\cos(\pi p_1/4)$ or $\cos(\pi p_2/6)$ equals $(2+\sqrt2)/4$ for each integer $p_1\in\{1,3\}$ and $p_2\in\{1,5\}$, we obtain the desired contradiction.

Comment: Could you please make it more understandable about the part "By considering Galois conjugates of primitive roots of unity, we can show that over the rationals, the algebraic degree of $\cos(pπ/q)$ is $ϕ(q)$ when $q$ is even, and $ϕ(q)/2$ when $q$ is odd."

Comment: @SoorajS Do you mean you want an elaboration on the answer I linked to?