# Minimal polynomial of $\omega:=\zeta_7+\overline{\zeta_7}$

Tags: polynomials, extension-field

Let $\omega:=\zeta_7+\overline{\zeta_7}$, where $\zeta_7$ is a primitive $7$th root of $1$. I want to find the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. 
I've found
$$\omega=\zeta_7+\overline{\zeta_7}\quad;\quad\omega^2=\zeta_7^2+\overline{\zeta_7}+2\quad;\quad\omega^3=\zeta_7^3+\overline{\zeta_7}^3+3\omega$$

Now how can I find the minimal polynomial?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460930/minimal-polynomial-of-zeta-zeta-1/). Probably others too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have :

$$
\omega=\zeta+\zeta^6, \ \ \ \omega^2=\zeta^2+\zeta^5+2, \ \ \
\omega^3=\zeta^3+\zeta^4+3\omega
$$

Adding all those three up, you obtain

$$
\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega =\sum_{k=1}^{6} \zeta^k+(3\omega+2)=
-1+(3\omega+2)=3\omega+1
$$

So

$$
\omega^3+\omega^2-2\omega-1=0
$$

Since that polynomial has degree three and no rational root, it is irreducible.
So it is the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

You seek to solve

$$ a + b \omega + c \omega^2 + d \omega^3 = 0$$

for $(a,b,c,d)$. That looks like a linear algebra problem.

The general purpose method is:

- Choose a basis for the 6-dimensional rational vector space $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$.
- Find the coefficients of $\omega^i$  with respect to this basis
- Arrange them into a suitable matrix equation
- Solve.