# Let, $\alpha$ be a root of $x^{7}-1$ ($\alpha\ne1$), then determine $[ \mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\alpha^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This is a review question, basically the question was written where $\alpha$ was a root of $x^{7}-1$ such that $\alpha \ne 1$, and we were asked to determine,
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}],$$
and I have determined that to be $6$, since we can assume $\alpha^{7}=1$ since the group of unity corresponding to this question is of order $7$. I'm now tasked with finding $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \alpha^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}]$. I know that, $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha^{6}$, so this question can be rewritten as find:
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \alpha^6):\mathbb{Q}].$$
I know I could let $\omega = \alpha + \alpha^{6}$ and attempt to find an irreducible polynomial by proceeding with: $\omega^2 = \alpha^5 + 2 + \alpha^2$, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to determine this without resorting to that tactic. Any help would appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: For a different approach observe $\alpha^{-1}$ is the complex conjugate of $\alpha$. Show first that $\alpha+\alpha^{-1}$ is stable under complex conjugation. What does Galois theory tell you?

Comment: Search the site for questions about cyclotomic fields. I'm sure we have covered this one (under one of the mentioned tags).

Comment: Hint:- $\alpha\neq 1$ is a root of $1+x+...+x^{6}$. And this polynomial is irreducible(known as the cyclotomic polynomial) . See Dummit and Foote pg 554  .

Comment: "we can assume $\alpha^7=1$": that's literally the given assumption "$\alpha$ is a root of $x^7-1$".

Comment: In general, $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}):\Bbb Q]=\phi(n)/2$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511891/minimal-polynomial-of-omega-zeta-7-overline-zeta-7?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that $\alpha\not=1$ (in that case there's no extension) and $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/7}$, all of the roots are primitive so it does not care. Since $e^{2\pi i/7}=\cos(2\pi/7)+i\sin(2\pi/7)$ and $|\alpha|=1$, it implies that $\alpha^{-1}=\bar\alpha=cos(2\pi/7)-i\sin(2\pi/7)$. It follows that $\alpha+\alpha^{-1}=2\cos(2\pi /7)$. Now there are two ways to calculate the degree of the extension:

First one:
$$\alpha=cos(2\pi/7)-i\sin(2\pi/7)\implies (\alpha-cos(2\pi/7))^2=-\sin^2(2\pi/7)\implies \alpha^2-2\cos(2\pi/7)\alpha+\cos^2(2\pi/7)=-\sin^2(2\pi/7)\implies \alpha^2-2\cos(2\pi/7)\alpha+1=0$$
So $\alpha$ is root of the irreducible polynomial $f(t)=t^2-2\cos(2\pi/7)t+\cos^2(2\pi/7)\in\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/7))[t]$. So it implies that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/7)]=2$, and since $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=6$, we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/7):\mathbb{Q}]=3$

Second one:

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the rationals is the cyclotomic polynomial of order $7$, $g(t)=t^6+t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1$. We can multiplie both sides by $t^{-3}$, getting:
$$t^{-3}g(t)=(t^3+t^{-3})+(t^2+t^{-2})+(t+t^{-1})+1$$
It's easy to manipulate it to get the irreducible polynomial
$$t^{-3}g(t)=x^3+x^2-2x-1$$
where $x=t+t^{-1}$. So $\alpha+\alpha^{-1}$ is root of $h(t)=t^3+t^2-2t-1$, so it implies that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\alpha^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$